# SQL - How to Multiply Prior Row value to Current Row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can this be done and if so what is the best approach. I tried Over(Partition) but cannot figure out how to add the prior columns. Should I use IF BEGIN ENDS and just walk through it row by row for running balance? Any assistance on initial direction would be appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PStatement](
[ID] [int],
[Source] [nvarchar](255),
[PaymentNumber] [int],
[PaymentAmt] [money],
[RBalance] [money],
[CBalance] [money],
[AllocationPercent] [float]
```

)

With the following values:

```
INSERT INTO PStatement (ID, [Source], PaymentNumber, PaymentAmt, RBalance, CBalance, AllocationPercent)
VALUES (1, N'SR', 1, 0, 7500, 10000, .75)
,(2, N'ER', 1, 0, 2500, 10000, .25)
,(3, N'SR', 2, 50, 0, 11000, 0)
,(4, N'ER', 2, 75, 0, 11000, .0)
,(5, N'SR', 3, 50, 0, 12000, 0)
,(6, N'ER', 3, 75, 0, 12000, .0)
```

I need to take the CBalance from the prior row, subtract the sum of the current rows PaymentAmt and multiple that amount by the prior rows AllocationPercentage and then add back the PaymentAmt based on PaymentNumber and Source.

So Row 3 RBalance is $11000 - ($50 + $75) (from current row) * .75 (from prior row) + 50 (from current row), AllocationPercent is RBalance/CBalance.

So Row 4 is $11000 - ($50 + $75) * .25 + 75

The end table would look like this:

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: It's confusing what are you trying to achieve? What columns are in your source table and what is your desired output?

Comment: It's the same table, I am trying to basically do a running total that updates the RBalance and the AllocationPercent columns.  I'll run a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can access 'prior row' data by using something like:

```
select ID
     , PaymentAmt
     , PreviousPaymentAmt=LAG(PaymentAmt,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY ID) 
from PStatement
```

The 2nd parameter in LAG is telling it to go only 1 record back; and the third parameter is telling it to return 0 (zero) if there are no prior rows.

Comment: Great, thank you.

Comment: If it solves your problem would you accept it as answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got it to work.

```
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @id INT, @Source NVARCHAR(255), @CBalance MONEY, @RBalance MONEY, @PaymentAmt MONEY, @AllocationPercent decimal(18,10), @PaymentNumber INT, @Amount MONEY;
BEGIN
    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT ID FROM PStatement ORDER BY Source, PaymentNumber     
    OPEN @MyCursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
    INTO @id

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
      SELECT @Source = Source, @PaymentNumber = PaymentNumber, @CBalance = CBalance, @PaymentAmt = PaymentAmt  FROM PStatement WHERE ID = @id
          IF(@PaymentNumber = 1)  
            BEGIN
            UPDATE PStatement SET AllocationPercent = RBalance/ CAST(CBalance AS decimal(18, 10))  WHERE (ID = @id)
            SET @AllocationPercent = (SELECT AllocationPercent FROM PStatement WHERE (ID = @id))
            END
        ELSE  
            BEGIN
            SET @PaymentAmt = (SELECT SUM(PaymentAmt) FROM PStatement WHERE (PaymentNumber = @PaymentNumber))
            SET @RBalance = ((@CBalance -  @PaymentAmt) * @AllocationPercent) + @PaymentAmt

            UPDATE PStatement SET RBalance = @RBalance WHERE (ID = @id)
            UPDATE PStatement SET AllocationPercent = RBalance/ CAST(CBalance AS decimal(18, 10))  WHERE (ID = @id)
        
            SET @AllocationPercent = (SELECT AllocationPercent FROM PStatement WHERE (ID = @id))
        
        END

      FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
      INTO @id 

    END; 

    CLOSE @MyCursor ;
    DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
END;
```